# Parsing results from query of HealthKit

Tags: swift, parsing, healthkit

How do you parse information received from a query?  I am looking to get the active calories burned using the following:

```
func getActiveEnergy() {

    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let now = Date()
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: now)

    guard let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: now) else {
        fatalError("*** Unable to create the start date")
    }
    print("startDate -> \(startDate)")

    guard let endDate = calendar.date(from: components) else {
        fatalError("*** Unable to create the end date")
    }
    print("endDate -> \(endDate)")

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: [])

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: true)

    guard let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned) else {
        fatalError("*** This method should never fail ***")
    }

    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), sortDescriptors: [sort]) { (query, results, error) in

        guard let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else {

            print("There was an error creating the query")
            return
        }

        for sample in samples {

            print("sample from query -> \(sample)")

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

        }
    }
    self.healthKit.execute(query)
}
```

The results produce a string of information:

0.055 kcal 0FBBA46F-F9C0-4BB7-87F2-84B567900084 "Kevin’s Series 4" (6.2.1), "Watch5,2" (6.2.1)"Apple Watch"  (2020-04-14 17:05:27 -0400 - 2020-04-14 17:05:37 -0400)

I only want the value (double) at the beginning of the string.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: `for sample in samples { print(sample.quantity) }`, or sample.something...

Comment: That is what I was looking for.  Thank you!